# Python ID3 tags, truple and string formatting issue

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to get the "title" and "artist" of every music file in a directory so I can so stuff with it. I'm a newbie so I'm using this guys code: http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/index.html

Right, so I've got the following output. Using my elite image manipulation skillset, I've pointed out what data I would like to keep:

[image: output]

Using the following code:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
  for info in listDirectory("/home/alpha/htdocs/music/", [".mp3"]):
      for song in info.items():
              print song[1]
```

Full code:

```
import os
import sys
from UserDict import UserDict

def stripnulls(data):
    "strip whitespace and nulls"
    return data.replace("\00", "").strip()

class FileInfo(UserDict):
    "store file metadata"
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        UserDict.__init__(self)
        self["name"] = filename

class MP3FileInfo(FileInfo):
    "store ID3v1.0 MP3 tags"
    tagDataMap = {"title"   : (  3,  33, stripnulls),
                  "artist"  : ( 33,  63, stripnulls),
                  "album"   : ( 63,  93, stripnulls),
                  "year"    : ( 93,  97, stripnulls),
                  "comment" : ( 97, 126, stripnulls),
                  "genre"   : (127, 128, ord)}

    def __parse(self, filename):
        "parse ID3v1.0 tags from MP3 file"
        self.clear()
        try:                               
            fsock = open(filename, "rb", 0)
            try:                           
                fsock.seek(-128, 2)        
                tagdata = fsock.read(128)  
            finally:                       
                fsock.close()              
            if tagdata[:3] == "TAG":
                for tag, (start, end, parseFunc) in self.tagDataMap.items():
                    self[tag] = parseFunc(tagdata[start:end])               
        except IOError:                    
            pass                           

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if key == "name" and item:
            self.__parse(item)
        FileInfo.__setitem__(self, key, item)

def listDirectory(directory, fileExtList):                                        
    "get list of file info objects for files of particular extensions"
    fileList = [os.path.normcase(f)
                for f in os.listdir(directory)]           
    fileList = [os.path.join(directory, f) 
               for f in fileList
                if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in fileExtList] 
    def getFileInfoClass(filename, module=sys.modules[FileInfo.__module__]):      
        "get file info class from filename extension"                             
        subclass = "%sFileInfo" % os.path.splitext(filename)[1].upper()[1:]       
        return hasattr(module, subclass) and getattr(module, subclass) or FileInfo
    return [getFileInfoClass(f)(f) for f in fileList]                             

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for info in listDirectory("/music/_singles/", [".mp3"]): 
        print "\n".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in info.items()])
        print
```

But I'm stuck after that because I have no idea what to do next. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Added code as text to clear up any issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got that data in info, then just access what you want via:

```
info['artist']
info['album']
```

etc... anything in your mapping

Comment: Works!!! How do I make it so that it checks if the data actually contains that parameter (to prevent errors)?

Comment: All the keys listed in `tagDataMap` will be set - some may be blank... but they're guarenteed to be set the way your code is written

Answer (score 3):

You're probably better off using a library like [Mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/).

```
import mutagen, mutagen.mp3, mutagen.easyid3

mp3 = mutagen.mp3.MP3(file, ID3=mutagen.easyid3.EasyID3)
print mp3['artist'], mp3['album'], mp3['title']
```

One benefit of Mutagen over your MP3FileInfo is ID3v2 support. You're just reading the old, simple ID3v1 tags. Mutagen parses all standard ID3v2.4 frames.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just installed it using pip, I'll give it a go. Got any example code to scan directory?

Answer (score 0):

In your main loop, `info` is a dictionary, with keys that you can see defined in `tagDataMap` in the `MP3FileInfo` class. So modifying your original code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for info in listDirectory("/music/_singles/", [".mp3"]): 
        print "\n".join(["%s=%s" % (k, info[k]) for k in ("title", "artist")])
        print
```